# Add DNS zone configuration to an Azure Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-app-configuration, azure-private-link

I would like to add DNS zone configuration using the command line, but was unable to find the equivalent command-line commands.

[image]

Comment: hello , may i know if you are looking for this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.dns/new-azdnszone?view=azps-6.5.0#example-4--create-a-dns-zone-with-delegation-by-specifying-parent-zone-name

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, you are trying to create a dns zone for the private end point associate to web app you can use this cmdlet 

New-AzPrivateDnsZone
   -ResourceGroupName <String>
   -Name <String>
   [-Tag <Hashtable>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]

Here is the reference documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.privatedns/new-azprivatednszone?view=azps-6.5.0

Answer (score 1):

try to follow the steps outlined in this guide. It should provide you the steps to do this with PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-powershell#configure-the-private-dns-zone

Comment: The above comments doesn't solve the question what's the exact answer ?